# Unable to port forward with the port range syntax in Docker SDK

Tags: docker, go, port, docker-run

I am trying to run a Docker container using Go SDK. From the terminal, I can run the following command with no issues :

```
docker run -d --memory 1024M --name "cdb1" -p 2001-2006:8091-8096 -p 11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase
```

I want to achieve the same thing using the [Docker SDK for Go](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) but cannot find how to reproduce the `-p 2001-2006:8091-8096` part. Here is my ContainerCreate call :

```golang
cont, err := cli.ContainerCreate(
    context.Background(),
    &container.Config{
        Image: "couchbase",
        ExposedPorts: nat.PortSet{
            "2001-2006": struct{}{},
            "11210-11211": struct{}{},
        },
    },
    &container.HostConfig{
        PortBindings: nat.PortMap{
            "8091-8096": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2001-2006",
                },
            },
            "11210-11211": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "11210-11211",
                },
            },
        },
        Resources: container.Resources{
            Memory: 1024 * 1000000,
        },
    },
    nil,
    "cdb1",
)
```

But running this always throw the same error :

```
Error response from daemon: invalid port specification: "8091-8096"
```

Doing some more testing, the error seems to come specifically from the `PortBindings` part (if I remove this one and leave the exposed ports, it works fine).

I couldn't find anything about this on Docker documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nat.PortSet`](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat#PortSet) is a map with [`nat.Port`](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat#Port) being its key type:

```
type PortSet map[Port]struct{}
```

Your "port" specification of `"2001-2006"` syntactically works because it's an untyped string constant and can be converted to `nat.Port` which has `string` as its underlying type, but this string literal lacks the protocol specification (e.g. `tcp` or `udp`).

Instead use the [`nat.NewPort()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat#NewPort) function to create the key:

```
ports1, err := nat.NewPort("tcp", "2001-2006")   // check err
ports2, err := nat.NewPort("tcp", "11210-11211") // check err

ExposedPorts: nat.PortSet{
    ports1: struct{}{},
    ports2: struct{}{},
},
```

Note that the expected "raw" string format is `"2001-2006/tcp"` which would also be accepted, but it's better to leave this internal detail to `nat.NewPort()`.

And to construct a [`nat.PortMap`](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat#PortMap), use the [`nat.ParsePortSpec()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat#ParsePortSpec) utility function. This is how you can assemble your `PortBindings`:

```
portBindings := nat.PortMap{}

for _, rawMapping := range []string{
    "0.0.0.0:2001-2006:8091-8096",
    "0.0.0.0:11210-11211:11210-11211",
} {
    mappings, err := nat.ParsePortSpec(rawMapping)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, pm := range mappings {
        portBindings[pm.Port] = []nat.PortBinding{pm.Binding}
    }

}
```

Then you can use the `portBindings` above for `HostConfig.PortBindings` field:

```
&container.HostConfig{
    PortBindings: portBindings ,
    Resources: container.Resources{
        Memory: 1024 * 1000000,
    },
},
```

Comment: Seems indeed a better practice to use NewPort. However it doesn't solve my issue, I still cannot use the range syntax inside the PortBinding section for some reason :/ (using your suggestion works in ExposedPorts but I still have the same error from PortBindings, only the splitted up syntax suggested by @NeoAnderson works for now)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add each port individually instead of the ports range:

```
cont, err := cli.ContainerCreate(
    context.Background(),
    &container.Config{
        Image: "couchbase",
        ExposedPorts: nat.PortSet{
            "2001": struct{}{},
            "2002": struct{}{},
            "2003": struct{}{},
            "2004": struct{}{},
            "2005": struct{}{},
            "2006": struct{}{},
            "11210": struct{}{},
            "11211": struct{}{}
        },
    },
    &container.HostConfig{
        PortBindings: nat.PortMap{
            "8091": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2001",
                },
            },
            "8092": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2002",
                },
            },
            "8093": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2003",
                },
            },
            "8094": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2004",
                },
            },
            "8095": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2005",
                },
            },
            "8096": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "2006",
                },
            },
            "11210": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "11210",
                },
            },
            "11211": []nat.PortBinding{
                {
                    HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
                    HostPort: "11211",
                },
            }
        },
        Resources: container.Resources{
            Memory: 1024 * 1000000,
        },
    },
    nil,
    "cdb1",
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's indeed a solution but it looks kind of "forced" to me. I'd especially love a condensed solution similar to what I can do from the terminal, since I plan to make the ports configurable (replacing `2001-2006` with a variable).

Is their a reason why the range notation `xxxx-xxxx` works (or at least seems to work) in the `ExposedPorts` field but not in the `PortBindings` one ?